# How to add a single backslash in array

Tags: ruby, hex, backslash

I have a string

```
a = "IN-EN00-456"
```

I need to convert it into hexcode in the form of

```
"\x49\x4e\x2d\x45\x4e\x30\x30\x2d\x34\x35\x36"
```

Can anyone help me in this? I tried:

```
a.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16)}.join("")
# => "494e2d454e30302d343536"

a.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16)}.join("\x")
# >> SyntaxError: (irb):3: invalid hex escape

a.each_byte.map { |b| "\x" + b.to_s(16)}.join
```

but not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a backslash in a double quoted string (as a result), you have to escape it with another backslash. Otherwise ruby will at this point try to resolve the hex-literal which is not possible because it is not followed by two valid hex characters (at the point where you use it). But escaping the backslash yields

```
puts "\\x"
# => \x
```

Alternatively you can use single quoted string literals.

```
puts '\x'
# => \x
```

Also note that join puts the seperator only in between the single members of your collection and not in front. Since you want your `\x` before every byte as I understood it you should first map all elements of your array and then join with blanks.

This applied to your own approaches should actually already work fine:

```
a.each_byte.map {|b| '\x' + b.to_s(16) }.join
```

or

```
a.each_byte.map {|b| "\\x#{b.to_s(16)}" }.join
```

produces for me

```
# => "\\x49\\x4e\\x2d\\x45\\x4e\\x30\\x30\\x2d\\x34\\x35\\x36"
```

which is the internal representation of

```
\x49\x4e\x2d\x45\x4e\x30\x30\x2d\x34\x35\x36
```

as you requested.